# How to calculate IsGrounded more effective?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

```
    if (SimpleInput.GetButtonDown(jumpButton) && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.AddForce(0f, 8f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.CheckCapsule(Char_Collider.bounds.center, new Vector3(Char_Collider.bounds.center.x, Char_Collider.bounds.min.y, Char_Collider.bounds.center.z), Char_Collider.radius * 0.27f, GroundLayers);
    }
```

I've multiplied `Char_Collider.radius` with 0.27f 'cause in the tutorial that guy said `You need to multiply this with %90 of your character's actual size` **That might be the problem** because i don't actually know my character's size, i've made it in blender and scaled it down at the unity.

So if you look at the inspector panel you'll see it's `0.1 0.1 0.1` but it's actually not. I tried to spawn a cube and match them together roughly, cube's size was `0.3 1.2 0.3`, that's way the number is 0.27f 'cause i just simply calculated it with the 0.3.

And finally my problem is:

I get return values from IsGrounded **delayed**, sometimes doesn't even get a value. Like example when i jump, sometimes it returns the value of `IsGrounded False` when i'm just about the hit the ground, and sometimes it doesn't returns the value of `IsGrounded False`. Because of this i can't make jump animation properly.

This is my HandleAnimation() method (I call that from FixedUpdate()):

```
void HandleAnimation()
{
    if (!IsGrounded())
    {
        anim.SetBool("Jumping", true);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("Jumping", false);
    }
}
```

And this is my animator:

[image: Animator]

I am also adding those because sometimes when IsGrounded() returns false, animation doesn't works.

Comment: We have [gobs of existing Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+grounded) about [performing ground checks](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+ground+check). Can you show us how you've tried implementing the solutions from these existing questions? I'm betting at least one of them will work for you, and if not, we can troubleshoot the particular issue you're having with it.

Comment: I've red all of the stuff that is related to mine. But those are not helping. Btw I've edited my question with new stuff you should check it.

Comment: In what specific way is it not helping? Without showing us how you've tried to apply this advice (like raycasts or spherecasts) and what went wrong, we're liable to just repeat the same kinds of tips that you've already deemed unhelpful. Help us understand what's so different about your case that the hundreds of tutorials that worked for other developers don't work for you, then we can try to fix that specific issue.

Comment: Raycasts are working fine i don't think that's the problem but it might be about the `IsGrounded()`. I'm just not feeling it's the right way to calculate because it has delay, i think it doesn't calculate it everyframe but maybe 30fps don't have any idea. The thing that's not working for me is animation, it's not applied when jumping but it does sometimes, it's simply RNG. I'm thinking maybe it's because of my animator or the `HandleAnimation()` code. I'm still researching here and the youtube for that animation problem, but there is nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests and researches my problem isn't the **IsGrounded** or **raycasting**, it's my jumpButton! I'll post an another question about that and link it to here if you guys want to check out.

So this IsGrounded() method is fine you can try it if this is your problem. Just make sure when multiplying `Char_Collider.radius with 0.27f`, You need to multiply it with your character's **Actual Size** not the `Collider's Size`.

Comment: Please accept your answer

Comment: I couldn't at the first time 'cause i needed to wait 40minutes but there you go